# How does C handle operation precedence in case of two increments and indirection operator?

Tags: c, pointers, operators, operator-precedence

Yesterday, I stumbled upon a sample code from university lecturer (I give private lessons to one of his students). I'm trying to understand, why and how does this code work, but I'm still not sure, even after a couple of hours of research. Here's what I have:

```c
int tab[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int* t = tab;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    (*t++)++;
    printf("%d ", tab[i]);
};
```

The result is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

So, this code is quite easy to understand, except for this part:

```c
(*t++)++
```

I know that incrementation operator takes precedence over indirection operator, so this operation will be most probably handled as:

```c
(*(t++))++
```

Considering that `t` is a pointer, I would say that this would happen:

1. `t` address will be incremented, so it will point to a second element in `tab` array (index 1).
2. Now, indirection operator should be processed, so the value of second element in `tab` array will be incremented, because we end up with `(*t)++`.

Now, my question is, why all `tab` elements are incremented? Shouldn't it skip the first `tab` element (index 0), considering that the pointer incrementation happens right at the start of the loop?

Comment: Post-increment means that the value of the expression is the old value, with side-effect being to update the stored value.  Similar example `int u = 0; int v = u++;` then the value of `v` is `0`.

Comment: Think *expressions* Side-effects are only ... *side effects*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator precedence says that `*t++` must be decomposed as `*(t++)`.
Thus the expression is like `(*t)++; t++;`

Confusion may come when you don't understand what `t++` means, the value of this expression is the value of `t` before the increment, and `t` can be observed as incremented after the (whole) expression being evaluated.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it! So it is actually like this: `(*(t++))++`, and `t++` is the first instruction to be processed, but the result of this incrementation is not set to `t` right away - it will be, but after the whole instruction is finished. That's why we have `t++`, and then `(*t)++`, which will be handled first. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine the evaluation of this expression

```
(*t++)++;
```

as a sequence of the following statements

```
int *tmp = t;
( *t )++;
++tmp;
t = tmp;
```

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postﬁx increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The result of the postﬁx ++ operator is the value of the operand. As
>   a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

Comment: There's no sequencing relation defined so this is not a great analogy IMO

Comment: @M.M The question is about how to understand the expression. and the answer explains this.